# PHP real_escape_string() - allow emoji references

Tags: php, mysql, emoji, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a web service which inserts various user input into a MySQL DB.

My DB insert statement uses `$db->real_escape_string()` for security on all input.

However this seems to be stripping out emoji references from input, e.g. in the format `\ud83d\ude2e` (winking face).

The pertinent DB column has collation **utf8_general_ci**, as does the table.

Example:

- Before insert: "Foo bar! \ud83d\ude2e"
- After insert (via `real_escape_string()`): "Foo bar! "

Perhaps `real_escape_string()` is *supposed* to pull out things like this, for all I know, and so my problem may be obvious to people more knowledgeable in this field.

How can I allow the retention of the emoji references in the DB insert?

Comment: Well, you should use prepared statements instead for security/safety... but, you should also let us know what the collation and charset is for your table fields and database.

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: This is somewhat legacy code. I'm doing plenty of security checks before it gets anywhere near the insert stage. Updated question with collation info.

Comment: Thanks for the link - shame I didn't find that (or the duplicate question) in my searching beforehand.

Comment: Ok, legacy code, perfectly understandable... I've been there... still there in some cases. ;)

Comment: The linked answer recommends changing the collation from utf8_general_ci to utf8mb4, but I can't find any information on the potential ramifications of this for existing data. Can anyone comment? Would I expect adverse effects on any saved special characters in the database or anything like that?

Comment: Answering my own question (previous comment). From the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html): *"For a supplementary character, utf8 cannot store the character at all, whereas utf8mb4 requires four bytes to store it. Because utf8 cannot store the character at all, you have no supplementary characters in utf8 columns and need not worry about converting characters or losing data when upgrading utf8 data from older versions of MySQL. "*

Comment: Right @Utkanos ... upconverting to utf8mb4 should not need actual data conversions (not like going from iso to utf8 omg that was hell). But that article is old in that it does not mention about using the 520 collation. Also I think its a bit off about the varchar(191) issue... I thought that was fixed somewhere along the lines when they introduced 520.

Comment: @IncredibleHat - excellent, thanks. I'll do the conversion and hope for the best!